# RestfulAPI URI記述：どちらのほうが最適でしょうか？

Tags: webapi

RestfulAPI を設計しております。
URIはリソース的な記述が良いとされていますが、以下のようなケースの場合、どちらの記述がよいでしょうか？

対象：POSTメソッド

Aというリソースに対して、POSTメソッドで操作します。
操作には、以下のようなものがあるとします。
entry:新規追加
update:指定したAのIDに対して、パラメータを更新
copy:指定したAのIDを新規IDとして複製する
それぞれの操作によって、リクエストボディに含めることができる必須パラメータ等が異なります。

操作については、リソースではないので、URIに含めない案１のほうが良いと思いますが、opキーのパラメータにより、その後のパラメータを判断しなくてはなりません。
案２であると、操作によって、決められたパラメータがあるかをリクエストボディ内でチェックすればよく、また、URI毎の構文例として提示する際にもスッキリとドキュメント化できると考えています。

直感的に理解しやすいのは案２のような気がします。

案１：

```
URI：
  http://{host}/A/
リクエストボディ：
  {
     "op":"entry",
     ...
  }
```

案２：

```
URI：
  http://{host}/A/entry
リクエストボディ：
  {
      ...
  }
```

Comment: RESTfulなのにPOSTだけですか？RESTfulであれば新規はPOST、更新はPUTになると思いますが

Comment: クライアントがURIを指定するようなサービスではないため、PUTではなく、POSTによって実現しようとしています。DELETE以外のリソースに対する操作は全てPOSTという方針です。

Comment: RESTfulでない独自の規格を用いて設計をしている以上は、何が最適なのかは判断するのが難しい印象です。RESTFulだったらどう設計しますか？だったら回答はつくかもしれないですが、独自の設計に対して良い悪いの判断は、要件や要求や環境によることが多いと思います